# PayPal Debit or Credit Card not render when empty value is provided

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am doing an integration of PayPal but i do have an issue: in the code below, if the $("#DonorEmailID").val() is empty, the form is not rendered anymore

```
paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                layout:  'vertical',
                shape: 'rect',
                height: 36
            },
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    //https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/standard-card-fields/
                    payer: {
                        email_address: $("#DonorEmailID").val(),
                        phone: {
                            phone_type: "MOBILE",
                            phone_number: {
                                national_number: "14082508100"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    application_context: {
                        shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
                    },
                    purchase_units: [{
                        description: getPurchaseDescription(),
                        amount: {
                            value: $("#Amount").val()
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
```

Demo video: https://www.screencast.com/t/xdENMuUbcbWu
Is there any way to add the email_address property conditionally to payer? Or do you have another solution to this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                layout:  'vertical',
                shape: 'rect',
                height: 36
            },
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                var order = {
                    //https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/standard-card-fields/
                    payer: {
                        phone: {
                            phone_type: "MOBILE",
                            phone_number: {
                                national_number: "14082508100"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    application_context: {
                        shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
                    },
                    purchase_units: [{
                        description: getPurchaseDescription(),
                        amount: {
                            value: $("#Amount").val()
                        }
                    }]
                };
                var email = email_address: $("#DonorEmailID").val();
                if(email) order.payer.email_address = email;
                return actions.order.create(order);
            },
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected!